# Set Form Control Error - Error Name is a Variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-control

```
    private static addFieldError(form: FormGroup, fieldName: string, errorName: string) {
         form.controls[fieldName].setErrors({errorName: true});
         form.controls[fieldName].markAsTouched();
    }
```

Here `setErrors` is not as I would expect. This will set an error to the field with value:
`{errorName: true}`

[image: While debugging in Chrome]

I would like to use the `errorName: string` parameter of the function `addFieldError` as the key of the object I am adding to error collection, and not using key 'errorName' itelf.

How can achieve that?

Comment: `setErrors({[errorName]: true})`

Comment: Great! You can turn this into an answer with some explanation. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is output the variable value as a key name.

In your code the object key is `errorName` as string

```
setErrors({errorName: true})
```

But instead `errorName` is a variable to you and the value of this variable needs to be set as key name for the object computed.

```
setErrors({[errorName]: true})
```

This is an ES6 feature where you can get the key name computed from a variable.

Check `Computed property names` under [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)